How to use Steam Audio in Unity via scripting?
Has anyone worked with Steam Audio? I'm trying to rewrite my game from .NET to Unity and I want to use sound surround effects there using acoustic ray tracing, where everything should be calculated in real time without baking. I tried Meta XR Audio, but it turns out that you can't do without baking. I'm blind, so I have to avoid the editor as much as possible and solve everything only with scripting. I would need some advice to get started - how to make Steam Audio work, how to turn on all the supported effects and especially how to define the geometry. So far in my game I have defined all objects and terrain in 2d and only virtually without visual representation.
